# Is MVC parsing DateTime objects differently in ajax GET and POST actions?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Within my MVC4 project I am using a TextBox with a jQuery datepicker. I've formatted both to use the dd-MM-yyyy format. Then on behalf of a search action, I used an ajax GET action which is handled by my controller. The handling method uses a ViewModel as input. What I've noticed when debugging the results of this GET action, is that the dates were handled in MM-dd-yyyy format. However, when I use the POST action, dates are received in dd-MM-yyyy as I wanted.

I used Fiddler to see what is actually being send and saw the following:

GET  -> MyDate=04-11-2013 (in the url)
POST -> MyDate=04-11-2013 (in the body)

So no difference there. I then went to my action handler method in my controller and watched the result from the ViewModel input.

GET  -> viewModel.MyDate shows 11-04-2013
POST -> viewModel.MyDate gives 04-11-2013

So this almost makes me think that MVC parses DateTimes different on being a GET and POST. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So this almost makes me think that MVC parses DateTimes different on
>   being a GET and POST. What am I missing here?

You are not missing anything. That's exactly the case. In GET the dates are always expected to be in the form `yyyy-MM-dd` whereas for POST, the current culture is taken into account. You can read more about this here: http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx

Comment: Your answer surprises me a bit, but the link is quality stuff to read and convinced me that this is the case (and more importantly, why it is the way it is). Thanks!